# How to pass parameters and set properties while navigating to a new view model (initializeAsync)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the design pattern `mvvm`, I have a view model locator and a view model base class.

The view model locator finds what view is associated to the view model. I also wrote a navigation service and one of my methods (NavigateTo) takes in a parameter (an object). the method is to navigate to a view model associated with the view.

```
namespace StudentData
{
    public class StudentOverViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private DataSet studentData;

        public Icommand getDetails { get; set; }
        public DataSet _data
        {
            get { return studentData; }
            set 
            { 
                 studentData =  value;
                 RaisePropertyChanged(() => studentData);
            }
        }

        public StudentOverViewViewModel (DataSet studentData)
        {
             this.studentData = studentData;
             getDetails  = new Command(Details);
        }

        public async Task getDetails()
        {
            // api calls done to retrieve data and set studentData to the current student data
            await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<StudentDetailViewModel>(studentData );
        }
    }
}
```

For the second view model I have :

```
namespace StudentData
{
    public class StudentDetailViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        private DataSet Data;
        public DataSet _Data
        {
            get
            { 
                return Data;
            }
            set
            {
                Data= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
            }
        }
    }

    public StudentDetailViewModel(DataSet Data)
    {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    public override  async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
    {
        if(navigationData is DataSet)
        {
            Data = (DataSet) navigationData;  // after the page is initialized, the variables or properties/ models are not updated and is still null
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that in my `initializeAsync` method in the second view model, I set the value and property for data, but after the method is done it set all the values back to null.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
   private async Task InternalNavigateToAsync(Type viewModelType, object 
     parameter)
    {
        Page page = CreatePage(viewModelType, parameter);

        if (page is UserAuthenticateView)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new CustomNiavigationView(page);
        }
        else
        {
            var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as CustomNiavigationView;
            if (navigationPage != null)
            {
                await navigationPage.PushAsync(page);
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage = new CustomNiavigationView(page);
            }
        }

        await (page.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(parameter);
    }
```

Comment: You're going to need the share the code (probably in your navigation service) that creates the view and sets the viewmodel as the bindingcontext. My guess would be that isn't happening properly, and you may be creating a second instance of your viewmodel when the view is created (I see that a lot when people have the vm defined in the xaml).

Comment: Can you please share the code in your page where you call InitializeAsync and use that model?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, i really appreciate.when i first navigate to the page, i sets the binding context and then I call the initialize method with the passed in parameter implemented in the second view model. It does set the properties in the second view model but after the method is done, it sets all the properties back to null. I just added the method from the navigation service. @BenReierson

Comment: How did you find it sets all the properties back to null after the method is done? The value in your page becomes null? And I did not see a instance of StudentDetailViewModel in your page. You just use `page.BindingContext as ViewModelBase` and did you assign a model to the page as BindingContext  before this line?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am using a view model locator, that finds the view associated with the view model using a naming convension and I am also doing view model first navigation. I also debuged the code and I stepped through the code and I could see the properties are set but still does not display anything on the view. The model to bind properties to is in my view model and I bind my view to a view model  and the view model properties ( model)  @MSFT.

Comment: Can you share a test project with this issue? It's really hard to find out the cause through your description.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I found the problem, while i was setting my binding context in my  InternalNavigateToAsync , i was also creating a new instance in the code behind the xaml page which is wrong. Thanks i appreciate your response.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can write your solution as an answer and mark it. It will help more people with same problem.